# A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client in .Net 4

Tags: .net-4.0, request-validation

So, [this](http://www.asp.net/learn/whitepapers/aspnet4/breaking-changes/#_TOC7) whitepaper describes one of the breaking changes in .Net 4 to be the error message "A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client in", and the fix to enter  into the Web.config file

I have 2 problems with this.  Does this mean that any website where I want a wysiswyg editor like tinymce, or ckeditor, the requestValidationMode has to be 2.0?  What benefits do you lose out on in this case?  (if I lose no benefits to setting requestValidationMode to 2.0, why not set it by default so it doesn't break anything?)

In 2.0/3.5 I was able to set ValidateRequest on a page by page basis - this is of course still possible in .Net 4.0 , but in order to set it on a page level, I have to make a site wide change?  Does this not seem entirely backward?

Have I got this right/is this as rubbish as it sounds, or have I missed something?

Comment: possible duplicate of [A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/81991/a-potentially-dangerous-request-form-value-was-detected-from-the-client)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

seems to be already discussed in
[A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/81991/a-potentially-dangerous-request-form-value-was-detected-from-the-client)

Comment: Hm, sort of. It doesn't really address it being a .Net 4 problem, it really only looks at the general, how to cope with it issue.  I want to know if there's something specific we should be doing in .Net 4, and if you lose anything by setting requestValidationMode to 2.0